# How can I get the elements of an ArrayList that have a json elements inside?

Tags: android, layout, arraylist

I have this json that I put inside one arrayList (I have parse the JSON), and this arrayList I put inside one method to display the data in the layout. if I put more data in the database, he'll add more lines in my layout.

```
{
 "Car": [
   {
     "UID": "01",
     "Name": "Ferrari",
     "Description": "\"This a red car...\"",
   },
   {
     "UID": "02",
     "Name": "BMW",
     "Description": "\"Good car\"",
   },
 ]
}
```

Now, I want to display this elements in the layout, but I'm not sure how can I get it.... I'm trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work. Show me the row but not the content of the element. Note that the json go through the ArrayList cars

```
private void addCarInView (ArrayList<String> cars) {
.
.
.
     CarUID.setText(cars.get(0));   
     CarName.setText(cars.get(1));  
     CarDescription.setText(cars.get(2));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is not the same question. I have parse the JSON and I put this JSON elements inside of an ArrayList. Now, I want to know how can I get this elements from the arrayList to display in the view

Comment: Why you put them as `String`? create an object an store UID, name and description of each json object and then put these objects to your `ArrayList`

Comment: Can you show me some short code of how can I do it?

Comment: This is I get the json

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
   
   JSONArray jsonArray = json.optJSONArray("Car");
   
   for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
             JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             
             String uid = jsonObject.optString("UID").toString();
             String name = jsonObject.optString("Name").toString();
             String description = jsonObject.optString("Description").toString();

                    arrayListData.add(uid); 
             arrayListListData.add(name);

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing `String` in your `ArrayList` create another `Object` like this:

```
public class Car{

    public String UID;
    public String description;
    public String name;

public Car(,String name, String description, String UID){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.UID = UID;
  }
}
```

And then when your parsing your json add `Car` to your `ArrayList`:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourJson);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("Car");

for(int i = 0 ;i<jArray.size();i++){
 JSONObject item = jArray.getJsonObject(i);
 yourArrayList.add(new Car(item.getString("Name"),item.getString("Description"),item.getString("UID")));
}
```

And then easily set your `TextView` like this:

```
 Car car = youtArray.get(i);
 CarUID.setText(car.UID);   
 CarName.setText(car.name);  
 CarDescription.setText(car.description);
```

Comment: I suppose that in the last part I have to do a loop for: for(int i=0; i <cars.size(); i++){ Car car = cars.get(i); CarName.setText(car.name); CarUID.setText(car.UID); CarName.setText(car.name); CarDescription.setText(car.description); }My arrayList is arrayList<Car> carArray; and I have this error in the console String can not be cast in the

Comment: And if I put arrayList<Object> carArray; I have Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Car in this line Car car = carArray.get(i);

Comment: `cannot convert from Object to Car` your array should be like this `ArrayList<Car>`